# Struggling to get SVG hidden to work for some svg animations

Tags: html, css, svg

So I've got a menu that shows animations behind selections when selected. The problem is, I'm having trouble keeping these svg animations clipped within their parent container. I've tried overflow: hidden on the parent container but to no avail!! Any suggestions would be great. I've traversed the net as much as I could to the point where my only hope is directly with you guys. Thanks for any help :)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- MENU -->
    <div id="nav-menu">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="dots-overlay-black">
                <svg width="100%" height="100%">
                    <defs>
                        <pattern id="dots-black" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <circle fill="#000" cx="0.75" cy="0.75" r="0.75"></circle>
                        </pattern>
                    </defs>
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots-black)"></rect>
                </svg>
            </div>

            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col no-gutters">
                    <div class="col1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        CONNECT
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col no-gutters">
                    <div class="col2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" onMouseOver="show_figureAnim()" onMouseOut="hide_figureAnim()">
                        <div class="btn-figure">
                            FIGURE
                        </div>

                        <div id="figure-btn-anim">
                            <script src="javascript/figureMenuAnim.js"></script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col no-gutters">
                    <div class="col3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-home">
                            HOME
                        </div>

                        <div id="home-btn-anim">
                            <script src="javascript/homeMenuAnim.js"></script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col no-gutters">
                    <div class="col4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-design">
                            DESIGN
                        </div>

                        <div id="design-btn-anim">
                            <script src="javascript/designMenuAnim.js"></script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col no-gutters">
                    <div class="col5 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-motion">
                            MOTION
                        </div>

                        <div id="motion-btn-anim">
                            <script src="javascript/motionMenuAnim.js"></script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*-----------------------------------------// MENU \\-----------------------------------------*/
#nav-menu {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.menu.active {
display: block;
background: #fff;
}

.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5 {
display: block;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 36px;
color: #000;
background: none;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden !important;
}

.col1:hover, .col2:hover, .col3:hover, .col4:hover, .col5:hover {
color: #fff;
background: #000;
/*cursor: pointer;*/
}

/*______________________________/ BUTTON ANIMATIONS */
/* Animation visible on hover */
.col1:hover #connect-btn-anim, .col2:hover #figure-btn-anim, .col3:hover #home-btn-anim, .col4:hover #design-btn-anim, .col5:hover #motion-btn-anim {
visibility: visible;
}

/* Figure Button */
.btn-figure {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
pointer-events: none;
z-index: 1;
}

#figure-btn-anim {
position: absolute;
display: block;
height: inherit;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
visibility: hidden;
pointer-events: none;
}

#figure-btn-anim svg {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: auto !important;
}
```

**JS (SVG Animation)**

```
var animationData =
{animation code exceeds character limit so can't put this here}

var params = {
    container: document.getElementById('figure-btn-anim'),
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animationData
};

var anim;

anim = lottie.loadAnimation(params);
```

[Image showing the svg animation overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6s0F.jpg)

Here's an image of what it currently looks like. The red lines highlight the approx size of the parent container (.col2) with the SVG animation (figure-btn-anim svg) not being clipped.

I think that's everything but I could've missed other stuff out by mistake. Happy to answer questions if I've not been as clear as I could be. Thanks again for any suggestions.

Comment: Please create snippet, So we are easily to fix your issue

Comment: @jaydeep patel Could you elaborate on what snippet you want? I've attached the related code and a screenshot of it's current state.

Comment: How can i see output? With this code. :)

Comment: It's locally held on my machine. I was hoping not to have to put the files online as there are things I'd like to keep confidential.

Comment: I understand, Please provide us svg image, html and css. Without this we can't help you. :)

Comment: Updated the HTML and CSS section to include everything for the menu. I can't put the entire SVG code as it's an animation and exceeds Stack Overflows character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUST SOLVED IT!!!!!!

Instead of targeting the individual columns (col1, col2, col3) I just targeted the overall .col class.

```
.col {
    overflow: hidden;
```

This worked!